# mysqli php query going haywire

Tags: php, ubuntu, mysqli

So recently I moved my php files and database from my laptop where everything worked perfectly to my server (ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

And suddenly all my queries stopped working. So I started troubleshooting.  The needed php packages are all installed (you can check my phpinfo() at sibstechnologies.com/kaas.php). And the database connection works just fine. The result of the code below shows me that the connection worked, but the query returns null. (see this page here http://sibstechnologies.com/koekoek.php). I'm 100% sure the query works and the database exists, If I test it in mysql command line editor, I get the results I want.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php 
    include "db_connect.php"; 
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
       echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
    }
    else {
       echo "Connected.";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SHOW TABLES");
     $query_result=mysql_query($showtablequery);
            while($showtablerow = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
            {
            echo $showtablerow[0]." ";
            }

    foreach ($result as $row) {
     echo "nana \n";
     var_dump($row);
    }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks a lot, and if you need extra information let me know

Comment: I don't see `$showtablequery` defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: **mysql_fetch_array** and **mysql_query** are your problem, amigo. Take a closer look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the anwser. I was using php5-mysqlnd to communicate between php and mysql. But i was using an outdated php version.

If you have a similar problem make sure you are using the latest version of everything.

```
php --version
mysql --version
```

Enter those two lines in terminal and check whether or not those are indeed the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing libraries:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SHOW TABLES");
               ^---note the i
 $query_result=mysql_query($showtablequery);
                    ^---note the LACK of an i
```

This is not "suddenly stopped working". This is **NEVER WORKED IN THE FIRST PLACE**.

Comment: the foreach loop should still work right. This is just a page i threw up to test. The result i got on my offline page with this exact cod is: Connected.nana array(1) { ["Tables_in_SBS"]=> string(8) "acordeon" } nana array(1) { ["Tables_in_SBS"]=> string(5) "redev" } nana array(1) { ["Tables_in_SBS"]=> string(6) "topbar" } nana array(1) { ["Tables_in_SBS"]=> string(7) "webpage" }